# Are there any disadvantages of calling MDC.clear() at the beginning of processing instead of at the end?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, mdc

I like to use MDC logging fields in my applications because it makes finding all related log lines sooooo much easier. I also find it much easier to clear() the MDC context at the beginning of processing because I know where the entry point into my application is but there are many possible exception paths where myself or another developer may have forgotten to call MDC.clear().

So my question is, is there any disadvantage to the way I am doing it? clearing the context always as a rule of thumb at the beginning of processing vs the end.

To be clear if I was writing code from scratch I would do something like:

```
MDC.put();
try {
...
} finally {
  MDC.clear();
}
```

But sometimes I have to use a base class or something from a library which doesn't have any MDC related code and so I do it this way as I described because I don't want to copy a base class from a library just to add a few MDC lines of code...

Answer (score 1):

Its recommended to be cautious on this. If you refer to beginning of application, it does not make sense and `MDC` would not have anything at that time. I guess your reference is at the beginning of a request, but in this case if you do, there might be other requests being processed in parallel and clearing `MDC` would affect logging of all other requests. You can invoke `MDC.remove()` at the end of each request. Without knowing your exact application, this is all I can suggest.

Comment: Ok a little more context, I work on middle-ware applications so machine to machine request processing. So in my case ALL values in the context are only meaningful for the lifetime of that particular request hence I call MDC.clear() at the beginning of processing the next request.

Comment: MDC would help if your application is built with thread sharing model. If it uses something like Netty where a single event loop handles all requests, then it would help. For most other web applications, I have found printing just the thread number to be sufficient enough to identify the requests.

Answer (score 1):

Only difference in 
MDC.clear and MDC.remove is:
clear will remove all entries from ThreadContextMap (Map per thread MDC keep)
remove will remove only one key from ThreadContextMap if it exist.

But since you mentioned "from a library which doesn't have any MDC "

Please put this check:

```
if (MDC.getMDCAdapter() != null) MDC.clear();

and if (MDC.getMDCAdapter() != null) MDC.put();
```